# How can I find matches with sed (or similar) for configuration parameters?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sed, regular-expression

I'm pretty good at using php's `preg_match` (and similar) commands, and I'm also pretty good with regular expressions, but I don't do very well with `sed`.

I have two shell scripts I'm working on and I'd like to be able to pull some variables out of configuration files.

#### First File

The first file is an `.htaccess` file and I want to grab the web address, which is going to be in a block that looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.net$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The syntax of the `.htaccess` file is going to be pretty regular so I feel like I should use a pattern similar to `#.*(http.*?)\$#is` which does:

- regular expression
- delimited by #
- 0 or more characters before http
- start capturing at the http with the non-greedy symbol ?
- continue capturing until you hit an actual dollar sign (escaped)
- match case insensitive
- ignore whitespace / newlines

**How can I use that regular expressionwith a command like `sed` so that I get the part inside parenthesis if it matches, and nothing (empty string) if it does not match?**

Would I be better off using another command besides `sed` if I am used to php's PCRE?

#### Second File

The second file is a little different because it is an `.ini` file and so I wonder if there might be some shell magic (I use `bash`) in order to parse it. The chunk I want looks like this:

```
[Database]
database          = mysql://user:password@localhost/database
```

If I was using PHP and regular expressions I would do something like this:

```
#\s+database\s*=\s*mysql://([\:]+):([\@]+)@([\/]+)/(.*?)\s+#is
```

In PHP there is an .ini parser, but I want this to be a shell/bash script, not a PHP script

**How can I use that regular expression to get the database connect credentials?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use perl-like regular expressions, why not use perl (which is found on 99% of non-embedded Unices)?

Like:

```
perl -lne 'print for /(http.*?)\$/'

perl -lne 'print for m{database\s*=\s*mysql://([^:@]+):([^@]+)@([^/]+)/(\S+)}i'
```

`/.../` is the shorter form of `m/.../`. The `m/.../` one allows other characters than `/` and also pairs like `m{...}`, `m(...)`.

`something for @list` runs `something` looping as the `$_` variable on the values of the list. `m{...}` in list contexts returns the list of captured patterns (inside `(...)`). `print` without arguments, prints `$_`.

Comment: can you elaborate on the `for` and `m{}i` parts of the syntax?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
grep -oP <your_pattern> <your_file>
```

The `-P` ensures that `grep` will interpret your regex a la Perl and `-o` makes it return only what it has matched.

EDIT: Note that your `grep` may not necessarily support lazy quantifiers, so if you don't expect URLs to run over multiple lines, I'd use a greedy quantifier without the `/s` modifier.

Comment: that look very good! and with my good friend `grep` to boot! i'm going to give it a try! thanks!

Comment: I seem to be having a hard time getting `grep` to return only the part in the parenthesis